# The reputation page on Area51 is missing the "Trigger Rep Recalc" button

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, reputation-audit

The [reputation page on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation) is missing the "Trigger Rep Recalc" button.  All the other sites have it.  I'm using Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain *why* this happens. Area 51 runs off a branched version of the SE code base, so changes to Stack Exchange are usually reflected on Area 51 (if they apply at all) only weeks or months behind.

And as to how to fix it? Wait for a dev to notice this post and I'm sure it'll be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button has been added to [Area 51's reputation page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation).